# How to create a fast and lightweight UIElement

Tags: c#, wpf, google-maps, user-controls, uielement

I am creating a path of Markers to be displayed on a [GMapControl](https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/) in my C#/XAML (WPF) application. The control requires I create a UIElement to be overlaid on the map as a marker. I have created a very simple UserControl for this purpose, as follows:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Project.Resources.Circle"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Ellipse Width="5" Height="5" Stroke="Red" Fill="Red" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

However, when I build the line, creating anything up to 400 instances of this control, my application freezes. Since I can only seem to create UserControl's on the UI thread (and not in a Thread or BackgroundWorker), what can I do to speed up the creation of new Circle instances?

Is there a more *lightweight* UIElement than a UserControl? Any guidance on this appreciated.

Comment: How about directly deriving from UIElement and overriding the `OnRender` method? There you would draw your circle into the passed `DrawingContext` instance.

Comment: Or you directly use `Ellipse` elements instead of wrapping them in UserControls.

Comment: I couldn't use your second suggestion as Ellipse is a sealed class. Fortunately, I tried your first with only a UIElement in the XAML and using OnRender with a drawingContext.DrawEllipse() and the performance is leaps and bounds ahead of a UserControl! Did you want to put that as an answer or shall I?

Comment: Something even faster would be to use an Image control. The problem with WPF geometry is that it is tesselated on CPU side. However the Image has it's own disadvantages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a minimal derived UIElement like this:

```
public class Circle : UIElement
{
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        const double radius = 2.5;
        drawingContext.DrawEllipse(Brushes.Red, null, new Point(), radius, radius);
    }
}
```